# Powershell: Recursive Functions and Multiple Parameters in Start-Job

Tags: multithreading, powershell, recursion, parameters

I have been banging my head against a wall for a couple of days now trying to get Start-Job and background jobs working to no avail.

I have tried ScriptBlock and ScriptFile but neither seem to do what I want, or I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I have a number of recursive functions and need to split up the script to work in parallel accross many chunks of a larger data set.

No matter how I arrange the Start-Job call, nothing seems to work, and the recursive functions seem to be making everything twice as hard.

Can anyone give me a working example of Start-Job calling a recursive function and having multiple parameters, or point me somewhere where one exists?

Any help appreciated

Comment: It's not clear what is not working because you haven't shown us any code, or given us any output to go on. I'm not even sure I understand exactly what you are trying to do (Are you recursively starting jobs or just trying to start a script that calls a recursive function) or why multiple parameters are causing difficulty (what has multiple parameters? the recursive function or the script). A simple, complete example of what hasn't worked along with the output/error messages would resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
$sb = {param($path, $currentDepth, $maxDepth) function EnumFiles($dir,$currentDepth,$maxDepth) { if ($currentDepth -gt $maxDepth) { return }; Get-ChildItem $dir -File; Get-ChildItem $dir -Dir | Foreach {EnumFiles $_.FullName ($currentDepth+1) $maxDepth}}; EnumFiles $path $currentDepth $maxDepth }
$job = Start-Job -ScriptBlock $sb -ArgumentList $pwd,0,2
Wait-Job $job | Out-Null
Receive-Job $job
```

Keep in mind your functions have to be defined in the scriptblock because the script runs in a completely separate PowerShell process.  Same goes for any externally defined variables - they have to be passed into `Start-Job` via the `-ArgumentList` parameter.  The values will be serialized, passed to the PowerShell process executing the job, where they will then be provided to the scriptblock.

Comment: Yea but this doesn't have multiple parameters. Not sure why that is emphasized, but right now my guess would be that there is a call like `EnumFiles($dir, $filter)` which doesn't do what most people think it does.

Comment: If that's the case, `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest` should set the OP straight.  :-)

Comment: I updated the answer to make the scriptblock take multiple parameters.

Comment: This is a recursive function that runs as one job in the background. I interpret the question in a way that there is a performance problem. SO what I think was asked is a recursive function that on each recursive call, splits itself into a job